# React array map not updating when state array is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object `dashboard` stored in state.  Dashboard has a `groups` attribute that's an array of objects.

To update the groups, I added a callback

```js
// This is all in DashboardContext (useDashboard)
const [dashboard, setDashboard] = useState(props.dashboard);

const addDashGroup = (group) => {
    const newData = {
        ...dashboard,
        groups: [
            ...dashboard.groups,
            group,
        ]
    }
    setDashboard(newData);
}
```

Then, I map it to use.

```js
// This is used in a component that can see the `dashboard` variable with `useDashboard`
{dashboard !== undefined && dashboard.groups.length > 0 &&
    dashboard.groups.map((g, i) => <DashGroup key={g.id} index={i} group={g}/> )
}
```

However, when `dashboard` gets updated with the new groups, it doesn't update the component that uses `dashboard.groups` to map.

How can I get that component to update when `dashboard.groups` gets updated?

### Edit 1

How I call the update callback:

```js
// Part of the dashboard context.  Initial dashboard passed in as prop, then updated as needed.
const { dashboard, addDashGroup } = useDashboard();

// RTK-Query mutation
const [createDashGroup, {data: addedGroup, isLoading, error}] = useCreateDashGroupInDashboardMutation();

// Query above gets fired off when the form submits.  If it's successful, `addedGroup` gets populated (previously undefined).
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('created', addedGroup);
    if (addedGroup) addDashGroup(addedGroup);
}, [addedGroup]);
```

Comment: Updating state should indeed trigger a re-render.  Can you provide a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Checkout this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73157760/why-setting-the-state-through-settimeout-doesnt-render-the-correct-props-of-a-c/73158275#73158275 i feel like you are facing the same problem

Comment: Show how you are calling addDashGroup

Comment: Can you provide more of your code?

Comment: You're creating a *copy* of `props.dashboard` for your component's *local* state. This will have no effect on the state of the parent passing in the `dashboard` prop. To update the state of a parent component you need to do this: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: The short answer is: you move the `addDashGroup` function to the parent (rewrite it accordingly), then pass it down to your component and call it while passing the new group. This will update the parent's state, which passes down the (updated) dashboard for you to use.

Comment: @Dom Added more info to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Test update the state with:

```js
const addDashGroup = (group) => {
    setDashboard((old)=> {
        return {
        ...old,
        groups: [
            ...old.groups,
            group,
        ]}
    );
}
```